# jquery - minus today date from end date, if remaining date is less than 6 months give the message

Tags: php, jquery, date, laravel

I m working on a form validation, passport issue date and passport end date in laravel

```
 <div class="control-group">
    {!! Form::label('passportIssuedate', 'Passport Issue Date') !!}
    <div class="controls">
        {!! Form::date('passportIssuedate', null, 
     array('id'=>'issuedate',                   
    'class'=>'span8 form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <!-- /controls -->
    </div>


     <div class="control-group">
    {!! Form::label('passportExpirydate', 'Passport Expiry Date') !!}
    <div class="controls">
        {!! Form::date('passportExpirydate', 
    null, array('id'=>'expdate', 'class'=>'span8 form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    </div>
```

can i do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var todaydate = $.now();
var enddate = getElementbyID('#expdate').value;
var result = enddate - todaydate;

 if(result < 6 months){
   alert("the expiry date duration should be more than six months");
  }

});
```

any help, highly appreciated in advance. thnx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "enddate" and "todaydate" are instances of "Date" object, you can do

```
diffInMs = enddate.getTime() - todaydate.getTime();
diffInDays = diffInMs /1000/ 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var todaydate = new Date();
var enddate = new Date($('#expdate').text()); // input format is yyyy-mm-dd
var result = enddate - todaydate;

 if(result < 6 months){
   alert("the expiry date duration should be more than six months");
  }

});
```

Comment: if (resul < 6 months){ --- } //the 6 months comparison is not making sense how to calculate and compare this duration

Answer (score 0):

in moment.js i have completed my task

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js')  }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#lastdate').blur(function(){
            mydate();
        });        

    });

   function mydate(){
        var duration = moment.duration(6, 'M').humanize();
        var lastdate = $("#lastdate").val();
        var today = moment().format('L');
        var ldate = moment(lastdate).diff(moment(today));
        var Result = moment.duration(ldate).humanize();
        //alert(Result);
        if(Result <= duration){
            var itsays= "some text message";
            $(".classnametobeshowninview").html(itsays);
        }else{
            $(".classnametobeshowninview").html("");
        }
   }

</script>
```